# How to order shows for a certain day?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a query about joining showingdates  and showings table and get all the showings for a date and order them by time.

My showingdates dayfield is formed as  showdate(datetime) and shows `"2013-03-06 00:00:00"`

My showings performance_date field is again a  datetime and examples are

```
 "2013-03-06 20:00:00 , 
 "2013-03-06 21:00:00" .
```

How can  I make a query for that date and order them by time ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.

```
SELECT garbage
FROM trash
WHERE DATE(showdate) = '2013-03-06'
ORDER BY TIME(showdate) DESC
```

The time here is descending. Remove `DESC` to achieve ascending order.

Comment: what about if $showingdate is dynamic ? my bad I asked as a certain date it was an example .. sorry

Comment: @ytsejam You would need to show more code. I can't give you an answer without context.

Answer (score 1):

To get rows only from a specific date (no use of any function on the `showdate` column, so indexes can be used):

```
WHERE showdate >= '2013-03-06'
  AND showdate < '2013-03-06' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

To order by time (since all rows will have the same date, and the `showdate` has both date and time, simply order by that):

```
ORDER BY showdate
```